# can not setimage of uiimageview while pushing viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, pushviewcontroller

I am new on objective c and I am trying to set image of `UIImageview` while pushing `viewcontroller` 
I checked other answer and I did the same way they said it but its not working for me below is my code and i will explain other things in it

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    DetailViewController *svController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];



    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
    UIImageView* imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


    id obj = [[mainArray valueForKey:@"image"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {




          NSLog(@" image%@",image); //print this image<UIImage: 0xaa70700>

         NSLog(@" image%@",svController.image); //print this  image(null)
        [[svController image] setImage: image];

         NSLog(@" image%@",svController.image);   //print this  image(null)


    }


    else     {
         NSLog(@" image%@",svController.image);

                  [[svController image] setImage: [[mainArray valueForKey:@"image"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

              NSLog(@" image%@",svController.image);


    }


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svController animated:YES];

    [svController release];
    svController = nil;

}
```

below is my detailviewcontroller

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController{

    UIImageView *image;


}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
```

its connected to Xib and i have synthesized it

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    name.text = nameString;
    email.text = emailString;

     NSLog(@"%@",image); // print this <UIImageView: 0x9d73950; frame = (27 35; 204 181); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9db4050>>

}
```

its working perfectly when i send `NSString` and set them on my lable but not working for image it its so small thing but now i dont know what to do please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hear is the simple way, i am showing the example that u can set image in detail view controller

in your master view controller

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    if(indexPath.row == 0)//for 1st row
    {
       DetailViewController *detController = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
       detController.detailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];//setting the property for image
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:detController animated:YES];
       [detController release];//im doing without ARC
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
       DetailViewController *detController = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
       detController.detailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"123.png"];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:detController animated:YES];
       [detController release];//im doing without ARC
    }
}
```

and in your detail view controller

```
// .h file
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
{

}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain)UIImage * detailImage;//set a property for image that u are passing from master viewcontroller 
@end

//in .m file

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize detailImage;  //synthesise it

// and in viewDidload method 
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

  //set your passed image to image view
  self.ImageView.image = self.detailImage;   
}
```

---

`Better` would be just do like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svController animated:YES];
if(yourImage) //got UIImage reference then only set it
   svController.yourImgView.image = yourImageHere

.................
<<Another code here>>
..............
```

Thats it....

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, because svController's view has not been loaded at the time you try to set the image of its image view (so the image view will be null).

You need to pass the image itself to a property you create in svController, and set the image in svController's viewDidLoad method.

Comment: so what you saying i make property of uiimage and send image the way i am sending right now and then set that image to my uiimageview in viewdidload?

Comment: @PrakashDesai, yes. You do it exactly the way you would for a string.

Comment: sir how about i do the way Prince said doing every thing after pushing that viewcontroller? just after that line?

Comment: @PrakashDesai, That's not the way it's usually done. I don't know if that will work (I'm unsure of the timing of when the detail controllers viewDidLoad is called).

Comment: @PrakashDesai, it may work, but I think it's bad design. A controller should control its own view (by setting images in an image view or text in a label for instance) -- that shouldn't be done by another controller. Passing the data is the correct way to do it.

Comment: ok i got it passing data and setting that data in own view controller

Answer (score 1):

Set your `UI object` `intialization` afer `pushing` `view` `controller`.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svController animated:YES];
//set image here
```

Reason is `viewDidLoad` of `svController` will not be `called` and `loaded` yet and `imageview` will not have `reference` yet.

---

**EDIT** : 
`Better` would be just do like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svController animated:YES];
if(yourImage) //got UIImage reference then only set it
   svController.yourImgView.image = yourImageHere

.................
<<Another code here>>
..............
```

Thats it....

Comment: yes i got it but i have question why am i able to send NSString? before pushviewcontroller? i do like this   [svController setEmailString:@"Email Id not available"]; and its working and second question is so everytime i should do pass things after pushviewController?

Comment: As such you have IBOulet to UI Object but they will be loaded after you write these line of code with push or present or addSubView because UI object will not have refrence. Other than UI Object each member wll have reference once you alloc it.